# Override nginx http version on location block

Tags: nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http2, nginx-config, nginx-location

I'm trying to set up end to end http2 connections on a Amazon Elastic Beanstalk application. I'm using node js and fastify with http2 support (it works great on my local machine). By defaul, the nginx reverse proxy that EB creates on the EC2 instance where the code gets deployed, uses http/1.1, so I need to change that.

I have read [here how to do it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) (see reverse proxy configuration section). The problem is that if you see the `nginx.conf` file:

```
#Elastic Beanstalk Nginx Configuration File

user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    66982;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    include       conf.d/*.conf;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default     "upgrade";
    }

    server {
        listen        80 default_server;
        access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

        client_header_timeout 60;
        client_body_timeout   60;
        keepalive_timeout     60;
        gzip                  off;
        gzip_comp_level       4;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
        include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;
    }
}
```

In the last line `include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/*.conf;`, a file `00_application.conf` gets included. That file contains the following:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version  1.1;

    proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

And there you can see the `proxy_http_version` parameter I need to change to `2.0`.

Any idea how can I achieve that? I can add configuration files to `conf.d` and replace the entire `nginx.conf` file, but I do not really know how to change that value from there.

Comment: According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/765258/use-http-2-0-between-nginx-reverse-proxy-and-backend-webserver) ServerFault thead, you can't use HTTP/2 with the `proxy_pass` directive :(

Answer (score 0):

Create a file with extension .config inside the .ebextension folder for example 01-mynginx.conf

Inside the config file, use the files key to create files on the instance and the container_commands key to run system commands after the application and web server has been set up

```
files:
 “/etc/nginx/conf.d/01-mynginx.conf”:
 mode: “000644”
 owner: root
 group: root
 content: |
   keepalive_timeout 120s;
   proxy_connect_timeout 120s;
   proxy_send_timeout 120s; 
   proxy_read_timeout 120s; 
   fastcgi_send_timeout 120s; 
   fastcgi_read_timeout 120s;
container_commands:
 nginx_reload:
 command: “sudo service nginx reload”
```

Elastic Beanstalk automatically creates the 01-mynginx.conf file inside /etc/nginx/conf.d folder and is included in the main elastic beanstalk nginx configuration.